# C Program is not counting letter frequency from text file

Tags: c, arrays, file, arguments, frequency

I need to write a program that outputs letter frequency in a text file. It reads the text of a other text file. The problem is that most letters are counted correctly however a few get a huge frequency that is not correct. Could someone help me solving this?

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NLETTERS 26

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c, i, accum = 0, letter[26];
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    printf ("argument 0 = argv[0] = '%s'n", argv[0]);
    printf ("argument 1 = argv[1] = '%s'n", argv[1]);
    printf ("argument 2 = argv[2] = '%s'n", argv[2]);

    ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    ofp = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    if (ifp == NULL)
        perror("No input file");

    if (ofp == NULL)
        perror("Trouble making file");

    for (i = 0; i < NLETTERS; i++) {
        letter[i] = 0;

        for(; (c = getc(ifp)) != EOF; ++accum) {
            if (c >='a' && c <= 'z')
                ++letter[c - 'a'];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < NLETTERS; ++i) {
            if (letter[i] != 0) {
                fprintf(ofp, "%c:%5d",i + 'a', letter[i]);
                putc('n', ofp);
                fprintf(ofp, "%f%cnn", ((double)letter[i]/accum), 37);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input file is:

```
Hi my name is niels and i a tying to write code.
```

The output file contains:

```
a:    3
0.062500%

b:32767
682.645833%

c:1606416521
33467010.854167%

d:32769
682.687500%

e:    7
0.145833%

g:1606416545
33467011.354167%

h:32767
682.645833%

i:    6
0.125000%

j:    1
0.020833%

l:    1
0.020833%

m:1606416578
33467012.041667%

n:32771
682.729167%

o:    2
0.041667%

r:    1
0.020833%

s:    2
0.041667%

t:    3
0.062500%

w:    1
0.020833%

y:1606416530
33467011.041667%

z:32767
682.645833%
```

Comment: Initialize all elements from the letter vector to 0 :
int letter[26]={0};

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what happens. It should be very enlightening with this program.

Comment: Also, characters other than the digits `'0'`-`'9'` are not guaranteed to have contiguous representation.  `if (c >='a' && c <= 'z')` is not guaranteed to represent the set of all lower-case letters. See [**5.2.1 Character Sets**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C Standard.  While it *may* work in your environment, it doesn't *have* to.  And there's a **huge** difference between "happens to work" and "must work per the standard".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you misplaced your main code in the loop zeroing your array.
Change:

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    letter[i] = 0;

    while ((c= getc(ifp)) != EOF) {
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    letter[i] = 0;
}

while ((c= getc(ifp)) != EOF) {
```

remove the curly brace before `return 0` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `letters` array. Uniitialized variables will contain unknown values that lead to the behavior you are observing. It's also *undefined behavior*.

Try

```
int letters[26] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be nested inside of another for loop that goes from 0 to 25.  The nested and outside loops are also both using `i`.  This means that the outer loop will never see i = 2 as the inner loop will have moved it to 25.

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    if (letter[i] != 0) {
        fprintf(ofp, "%c:%5d",i + 'a', letter[i]);
        putc('n', ofp);
        fprintf(ofp, "%f%cnn", ((double)letter[i]/accum), 37);

    }
}
```

It looks like you'd print the alphabet 26 times to me.  Can you move the above code outside of the first for loop?

I'd rewrite as:

```
/*for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    letter[i] = 0;
}*/
letter = {0};

while ((c= getc(ifp)) != EOF) {

    if (c >='a' && c <= 'z')
        ++letter[c-'a'];
    accum++;

}

for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    if (letter[i] != 0) {
        fprintf(ofp, "%c:%5d",i + 'a', letter[i]);
        putc('n', ofp);
        fprintf(ofp, "%f%cnn", ((double)letter[i]/accum), 37);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you declare a variable or array, and you do not initialize it, then that variable will contain garbage. In this case, you need to zero out the `letters` array. That is:

```
int letters[26] = { 0 };
```

or (using `memset` from string.h)

```
int letters[26];
memset(letters, 0, 26);
```